# tax treatment of naked put LEAPS held more than one year

Tags: united-states, capital-gains-tax, put-options

Say I sold **ONE**,(**January 21,2022 AMZN 3100 PUT**) for $506.25 on September 16, 2020 and bought it back on January 21 2022 for $94.04. Is the Gain Long Term or short term ?

Answer (score 1):

All short options are taxed as short term capital gains regardless of how long the position is held.  This info can be found in IRS publication 550.

And for the trivia file, if you want to book a gain or a loss on a short position (equity or option), you need to close it two business days before the end of the year because settlement for short positions is handled differently than for long positions.